# Steps per epoch (with image augmentation) not changing with batch size

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, categorical-data, image-augmentation

I have read that one can increase steps per epoch by 2 or 3 times when applying image augmentation. I have also done that in the past with no issue, however this time I've got an error telling me I have run out of training data

Another issue I have is my steps per epoch in keras is always showing the same number even when I changed batchsize.

Here are some specs and sameple code:

training data size: 6149

validation data size: 1020

batchsizes tried: 32 and 64

augmentation and preprocessing steps:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet import preprocess_input
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=90,
                             horizontal_flip=True,
                             vertical_flip=True,
                             # featurewise_center=True,
                             zoom_range=0.3,
                             shear_range=0.5,
                             preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train', seed=42)
validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/validation', seed=42)
>Found 6149 images belonging to 102 classes.
>Found 1020 images belonging to 102 classes.
```

fitting:

```
batch_size = 64  #or 32
model.fit(train_generator, 
          epochs=100,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          # steps_per_epoch=3*training_size//batch_size, - gives error
          validation_data=validation_generator,
          callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

example output with batch_size 32 or 64:

```
Epoch 1/100
193/193 [==============================] - 3284s 17s/step - loss: 0.3660 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5357 - val_loss: 0.4022 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5176
```

error shown when I specified steps_per_epoch:

> Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 57600 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset

Summary:

1. Why is my steps per epoch always at 193 regardless of changing the batchsize? (without specifying steps_per_epoch)
2. Specifying steps_per_epoch resulted in error of not enough data.
3. Could there be a problem with my code for the generator?
4. side question: I have a large number of classes - 102, should my batch size be larger than that? I always overfit this data

Comment: Could you please provide the details of model definition and model compilation code to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the `batch_size` of the dataset at the dataset [generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory), so model has taken by default `batch_size=32` and divided with the training data size to calculate the number of steps per epochs.

**steps_per_epoch = training_data size/batch_size**

We should not specify `batch_size` in `model.fit()`, If the **dataset is in the form of datasets, generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances** (since they generate batches) and as you have not defined batches in generator, so by default `batch_size=32` taken, which do not change when you specify the `batch_size=64` in [model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). Please refer to the mentioned link for more details.

You can specify any number for the `batch_size` at the dataset generation, which will show effect in steps per epochs while model training:

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(data_train, batch_size=64, seed=42)
validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(data_valid, batch_size=64, seed=42)
```

Please have a look at this replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/60b31ff459cc34b637ed144df31974d8/75047706.ipynb).